# Difference between a struct and a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to understand the difference between a struct and a struct as a pointer. The following is the code example.

*code example*:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 typedef struct{
     const char *description;
     float value;
 } swag;

 typedef struct{
     swag *swag;
 } combination;
```

As you can see there are two structs here swag, combination. The struct combination has a pointer to the struct swag. Why can't we do something like this:

```
 typedef struct{
     swag swag;
 } combination;
```

Why does it have to be this `swag *swag`. Can someone please explain me the difference between the two code examples?

Comment: You can do your second suggestion. It doesn't have to be a pointer. The difference is that one has a pointer and one doesn't.

Comment: Thanks sir for your response.I tried out both examples and got the same output. Am trying to understand the difference between the two codes.As per my understanding ,I can mark that as a pointer when I want the swag struct and save up some space? Am I right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: typically the first case would use more space (you need to make space for a swag somewhere, so the pointer can point to it). Your posted code does not have any output. If you want advice about some particular code then you will need to post that code.

Comment: What is the difference between a house, and a piece of paper with a house address written on it?

Comment: @M.M: This is the original version of the code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are possible, this is how they will appear in memory:

#### Case 1

```
     +----+-----+----------+
  +->|    p     |   value  |      struct swag
  |  +----------+----------+
  |  const char*    float
  |
  |  +----------+
  +--+   swag   |                 struct combination
     +----------+
         swag*
```

#### Case 2

```
    +-----------------------+
    |+----+-----+----------+|
    ||    p     |   value  ||     struct combination
    |+----------+----------+|
    +-----------------------+
```

The advantage of case 1 is `swag*` may be pointing to `NULL` when there's no data and it can point to some allocated structure otherwise. While in case 2, it will always have to incur the space for the complete `swag` structure.

However, case 2's advantage is that there would be no memory management issues specific to allocating and deallocating space for the `swag` structure, since it is always there. Case 2 may be better for locality of reference since there's no pointer to dereference and spoil cache coherence. The total space will be lesser for case 2 when both cases hold data; case 1: `sizeof(swag) + sizeof(swag*)`; case 2: `sizeof(swag)`.

Answer (score 0):

The second example is fine, if that's what you want to do. A reason for using the first example with the pointer is to have an array of `swag` structs, which you would access with an index.

Answer (score 0):

Simple difference that can be easy to identify is the size of `combination`:

In the first case, the `combination` hold the pointer to the `swag` so the size of `combination` is 4bytes(in 32 bits system) event `swag` add or remove members. In the second case, the `combination` hold the value of `swag` so the size is 8 bytes(4 bytes of `description` address + 4 bytes of `value` type). Use the first case will save the memory and memory copying when you have many `combination` instances that reference to one `swag` instance.

In the first case when you assign the value to the `combination` instance, only 4 bytes of `swag` address is copied to `swag` member, but in the second case, 8 bytes is copied.

Use first one if you suppose to pass the value of `swag` around, use the second one if you suppose to hold the value of `swag`.

BTW: you better read about the pointer in C for more information. Cheer :D.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to create a self-referencing **struct**

Can be done like this:

```
    typedef struct tagswag{
    tagswag *pointerToSwag;
    // other menbers
    }swag;
```

Then:

```
   swag sw1,sw2,*ptrSw1,*ptrSw2;
```

You have to declare a type before you can declare a pointer to it, which is what the **Tag{** syntax does.

Comment: There is no self-referencing struct; `combination` contains (or points to) `swag`, a different struct

Comment: **  *swag  ** is a pointer to a structure of type **  swag  **